# how to go into a process running in PM2

Tags: node.js, linux, server, process, pm2

I can see all the processes using pm2 ls, but how can lo into a process and see the logs and make changes?

To make this question pass quality standards I'm adding these unnecessary lines.

Comment: Something from here might be of help: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/

Comment: @MadaManu yeah i saw that but how to ssh into the process?

Comment: I don't use pm2 on a daily basis, but from a quick look around their documentation that doesn't seem to be an option.

Comment: @amitavamozumder what do you mean by how to ssh into the process..?

Comment: pm2 runs the process in background as daemon, You can see the logs for individual  process using pm2 logs < process_id >. You can not make changes to running process. You can instead allow pm2 to listen to file changes and live-reload the process.

Answer (score 3):

Try

`pm2 logs "processId here"`

or

`pm2 monit "processId here"`